# python sphinx documentation

Tags: django, documentation, django-views, django-sphinx, sphinx4

Can any one tell me how can this  project be used for documentation purpose  http://sphinx.pocoo.org

I have successfully installed it on my CentOS machine .After installation The Readme file says to run sphinx-quickstart and root for documentation is /home/tom/Docs

Where to from here how can i use the commands in /home/tom/Docs i have files
  `__build`
  `conf.py`
  `index.rst`
  `make.bat`
  `Makefile`
  `_static`
  `_templates`

What next?how to generate reports for my django project which resides in /usr/my-site

Comment: Did you read any part of the Sphinx documentation?  What parts did you read?  Can you provide a specific quote from the Sphinx documentation that confuses you?

Comment: These are the three Parts,1.Defining Document structure 2.Adding content 3.Running the build.Please help me understanding these 3 parts

Comment: Also how to run the commands like :ref:`rst-primer`

Comment: @Rajeev: Did you define the document?  Did you write any content?  Did you try to run the build?  Can you be more specific on which step you cannot do?

Comment: @S.Lott:After the installation , i copied one of my project to the same directory then copied conf.py and index.rst to this folder.Then ran sphinx-build -b html admin builddir/ Then it says build succcessfull.My question is that how to view the report for this

Comment: @Rajeev: "My question is that how to view the report for this?"  Please **update** your question to actually say that.  We can't guess that this is your meaning.  You have to write your **real** question.  Please **update** this question to include what you **really** want to know.  Also.  Explain what you mean by "copy my project to the same directory".  This sounds wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're going to have to do some reading up yourself. However, as a basic overview:

- You would usually run sphinx-quickstart in a subfolder of your project for documentation (e.g. `/usr/my-site/docs`).
- You write Sphinx documentation in [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) (rst) format. Start by editing the index.rst file, and you can add more files later.
- When you're done, use `make html` (or make.bat html on Windows) to build the HTML files from your RST.

Comment: Thanks but after building the html what would be the next step..

Comment: @Rajeev: What next step? The HTML is your documentation. You can build it in other formats if you prefer (http://sphinx.pocoo.org/builders.html) but HTML is convenient.